# fetch all members of a server inside a funtion | property members undefined | package: discord-giveaways

Tags: javascript, function, bots, discord.js

So i am using the package "discord-giveaways" and i want to use the "exemptMembers" option which is a function and with which i can set who is not allowed to take part in a giveaway and i want that people who haven't joined a specific server cannot take part but i am not sure if coded that right and also there is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined` that i don't really know to fix, so it would be nice if someone can say me what i did wrong.

```
var server = require('./commands/giveaway/start-giveaway.js')
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(server)

// Init discord giveaways
const { GiveawaysManager } = require('discord-giveaways');
client.giveawaysManager = new GiveawaysManager(client, {
    storage: "./giveaways.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 5000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "0x0099ff",
        embedColorEnd: "ff0000",
        reaction: "",
        exemptMembers: !guild.members.fetch()
    }
});
```

If the function returns true then the member should not be able to take part in the giveaway: `exemptMembers: !guild.members.fetch()`

Please don't roast me to hard if i did it completely wrong .

The "start-giveaway" file:

```
run : async (message, client, args) => {
        const ms = require('ms');


            // Giveaway channel
            let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
            // If no channel is mentionned
            if(!giveawayChannel){
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to mention a valid channel!');
            }

            // Giveaway duration
            let giveawayDuration = args[1];
            // If the duration isn't valid
            if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))){
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
            }

            // Number of winners
            let giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
            // If the specified number of winners is not a number
            if(isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners)){
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid number of winners!');
            }

            // Require members to join a server if author does not say "no"
            if (args[3] !== 'no'){
                var server = args[3]
                console.log(server)

                if(!server){
                    return message.channel.send(':x: You habe to specify a valid server ID or say "no"')
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('User sayed no')
            }

            // Giveaway prize
            let giveawayPrize = args.slice(4).join(' ');
            // If no prize is specified
            if(!giveawayPrize){
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid prize!');
            }

            // Start the giveaway
            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                // The giveaway duration
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                // The giveaway prize
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                // The giveaway winner count
                winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
                // Who hosts this giveaway
                hostedBy: true ? message.author : null,
                // Messages
                messages: {
                    giveaway: " **GIVEAWAY** ",
                    giveawayEnded: " **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        weeks: "weeks",
                        months: "months",
                        pluralS: false // Not needed, because units end with a S so it will automatically removed if the unit value is lower than 2
                    }
                }
            })
            message.channel.send(`Giveaway started in ${giveawayChannel}!`);

    }
```

Comment: I think your issue is something caused by the value returned by the first line `var server = require('./commands/giveaway/start-giveaway.js')`, can you give details about that `start-giveaway.js` file?

Comment: I added it in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `start-giveaway.js` file will not return any server id when you require it in the first code sample you gave. So `let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(server)` will always be `undefined`.

By looking at [discord-giveaways documentation](https://discord-giveaways.js.org/global.html#GiveawayStartOptions) you can find out that in the options to start a giveaway you can define the `exemptMembers` property again, so this is what you should do :

Firstly, remove the `exemptMembers` property from the GiveawaysManager.
Then, modify `start-giveaway.js` file like below.

### Warning - May 19 '20

**`exemptMembers` property might not work properly right now, an [issue](https://github.com/Androz2091/discord-giveaways/issues/41) is currently opened in the [discord-giveaway GitHub](https://github.com/Androz2091/discord-giveaways) about it!**

```js
run : async (message, client, args) => {
    const ms = require('ms');

    // Giveaway channel
    let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    // If no channel is mentionned
    if(!giveawayChannel){
        return message.channel.send(':x: You have to mention a valid channel!');
    }

    // Giveaway duration
    let giveawayDuration = args[1];
    // If the duration isn't valid
    if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))){
        return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
    }

    // Number of winners
    let giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
    // If the specified number of winners is not a number
    if(isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners)){
        return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid number of winners!');
    }

    // Giveaway prize
    let giveawayPrize = args.slice(4).join(' ');
    // If no prize is specified
    if(!giveawayPrize){
        return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid prize!');
    }

    // Options for the giveaway
    let giveawayStartOptions = {
        // The giveaway duration
        time: ms(giveawayDuration),
        // The giveaway prize
        prize: giveawayPrize,
        // The giveaway winner count
        winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
        // Who hosts this giveaway
        hostedBy: true ? message.author : null,
        // Messages
        messages: {
            giveaway: " **GIVEAWAY** ",
            giveawayEnded: " **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ",
            timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
            inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
            winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{prize}**!",
            embedFooter: "Giveaways",
            noWinner: "Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.",
            hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
            winners: "winner(s)",
            endedAt: "Ended at",
            units: {
                seconds: "seconds",
                minutes: "minutes",
                hours: "hours",
                days: "days",
                weeks: "weeks",
                months: "months",
                pluralS: false // Not needed, because units end with a S so it will automatically removed if the unit value is lower than 2
            } 
        }
    }

    // Require members to join a server if author does not say "no"
    if (args[3] !== 'no'){
        let server = args[3];
        console.log(server);

        if(!server){
            return message.channel.send(':x: You habe to specify a valid server ID or say "no"');
        } else {
            client.guilds.cache.get(server).members.fetch().then(otherServerMembers => {
                // Who will be excluded from this giveaway if members have to join a specific server
                giveawayStartOptions.exemptMembers = (member) => !otherServerMembers.has(member.id)
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('User sayed no');
    }

    // Start the giveaway
    client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, giveawayStartOptions);
    message.channel.send(`Giveaway started in ${giveawayChannel}!`);

}
```

Like this, `exemptMembers` will be defined only if the author gives a server id.

Comment: kk thanks and yes it doesn't work probably cause my server has over 100 members and the emptmembers option just doesn't work propertly